# WebKit 537.36 - same version in most browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge, user-agent

Why do all browsers has the same WebKit 537.36 version? I know that's the "Blink" engine, but why all of them stay on the same version? Is this some sort of "identificator" for Blink engine? Will it change? Is there any documentation that answers why exactly that version?

Some examples:

```
CHROME - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
FIREFOX - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
OPERA - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.42
EDGE - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362
```

Answer (score 0):

Webkit is the layout engine of the browsers and 537.36 is the version number. It means that the browser's layout engine is developed based on WebKit 537.36.

Let's get [Chrome as an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history), the latest version of Webkit used in Chrome as the layout engine is 537.36. After that they use [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)), it's a fork of the WebCore component of WebKit. So I think that's why they use that version number.